Ubuntu Server 24.04.1 Samba Shares and Active Directory
I am pulling my hair out to make this work.
I have successfully joined this Ubuntu machine to AD following this:
https://documentation.ubuntu.com/server/how-to/sssd/with-active-directory/
I can verify that I can get a kerberos ticket with klist. I can ssh into the machine with my AD credentials so everything is working on that end.
Now that this is working, I wanted to setup samba so that I can assign AD groups to access some shares. There are bunch of tutorials on the internet which are all outdated and do not work.
I have also read a bunch of discussions with winbind and sssd. Considering the tutorial I have just followed, I have joined the domain with sssd, so how do I make this work? So confusing!!!
Windows Server 2022 DC hostnames are: WINSERVER1.AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG and WINSERVER2.AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG
/etc/sssd/sssd.conf
[sssd]
domains = ad.mydomain.org
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam
# services =
debug_level = 5

[domain/ad.mydomain.org]
default_shell = /bin/bash
ad_server = winserver1.ad.MYDOMAIN.org, winserver2.ad.MYDOMAIN.org
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
id_provider = ad
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
ad_domain = ad.MYDOMAIN.org
use_fully_qualified_names = False
ldap_id_mapping = True
access_provider = ad

/etc/krb5.conf
# [libdefaults]
# udp_preference_limit = 0
# default_realm = AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG

[libdefaults]
    default_realm = AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG
    udp_preference_limit = 0
[realms]
    AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG = {
        kdc = winserver1.ad.mydomain.org
        kdc = winserver2.ad.mydomain.org
        admin_server = winserver1.ad.mydomain.org
    }

[domain_realm]
    .mydomain.org = AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG
    mydomain.org = AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG

/etc/nsswitch.conf
passwd:         files systemd sss
group:          files systemd sss
shadow:         files systemd sss
gshadow:        files systemd

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files sss
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis sss
automount:  sss

/etc/samba/smb.conf
    [global]
    
    ## Browsing/Identification ###
    
    # Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
       workgroup = AD
       realm = AD.MYDOMAIN.ORG
    
    # server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
       server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
       bind interfaces only = yes
       log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
       max log size = 1000
       logging = file
       panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
       server role = member server
       obey pam restrictions = yes
       unix password sync = yes
       passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
       passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
       pam password change = yes
       map to guest = bad user

    ############ Misc ############
       security = ads
       template shell = /bin/bash
       # Enable Samba to work with AD
       kerberos method = secrets and keytab
    
       # Use the ID mapping backend for AD integration
    
       idmap config * : backend = tdb
       idmap config * : range = 10000-199999
       idmap config AD : backend = rid
       idmap config AD : range = 200000-2147483647

   
    [SharedFiles]
    path = /srv/samba/shares/SharedFiles
    browsable = yes
    writable = yes
    valid users = @sambashare, @Global-Admins
    create mask = 0777
    directory mask = 0777

